# Anyone know how to help me with prologue?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

On *Grand Theft Auto 5*, as I do mission 1/prologue I walk into the security room where it says "go to the guard" and when I go to the guard nothing happens. I have done the prologue before which I know that it's supposed to load when you walk into the room but it never did load. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am playing on a PlayStation 3 system.

Comment: Restart the mission from the beginning? Sounds like a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug in the game. Since this is the the beginning of the game's first mission other options like "killing your character three times to skip the section" are unavailable.

Your only option is to quit the mission, restart the game and check for game updates.